# Java compliation error when installing Spark on CentOS

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to install Spark on CentOS.  While building spark using the `sbt/sbt assembly` command it gives following error.

```
[warn] /root/spark-0.8.0-incubating/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkHadoopWriter.scala:129: method cleanupJob in class OutputCommitter is deprecated: see corresponding Javadoc for more information.
[warn]     getOutputCommitter().cleanupJob(getJobContext())
[warn]                          ^
[warn] /root/spark-0.8.0-incubating/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PairRDDFunctions.scala:592: method cleanupJob in class OutputCommitter is deprecated: see corresponding Javadoc for more information.
[warn]     jobCommitter.cleanupJob(jobTaskContext)
[warn]                  ^
[warn] two warnings found
[error] ----------
[error] 1. WARNING in /root/spark-0.8.0-incubating/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/network/netty/FileClient.java (at line 22)
[error]         import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture;
[error]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error] The import io.netty.channel.ChannelFuture is never used
[error] ----------
[error] 2. WARNING in /root/spark-0.8.0-incubating/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/network/netty/FileClient.java (at line 23)
[error]         import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener;
[error]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error] The import io.netty.channel.ChannelFutureListener is never used
[error] ----------
[error] ----------
[error] 3. WARNING in /root/spark-0.8.0-incubating/core/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/network/netty/FileServer.java (at line 23)
[error]         import io.netty.channel.Channel;
[error]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error] The import io.netty.channel.Channel is never used
[error] ----------
[error] ----------
[error] 4. WARNING in /root/spark-0.8.0-incubating/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaSparkContextVarargsWorkaround.java (at line 20)
[error]         import java.util.Arrays;
[error]                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
[error] The import java.util.Arrays is never used
[error] ----------
[error] ----------
[error] 5. ERROR in /root/spark-0.8.0-incubating/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/DoubleFlatMapFunction.java (at line 36)
[error]         public final Iterable<Double> apply(T t) { return call(t); }
[error]                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
[error] The method apply(T) of type DoubleFlatMapFunction<T> must override a superclass method
[error] ----------
[error] 5 problems (1 error, 4 warnings)
[error] (core/compile:compile) javac returned nonzero exit code
[error] Total time: 431 s, completed Oct 24, 2013 7:42:21 AM
```

The version of java installed on my machine is 1.7.0_45.
Earlier I used jdk 1.6.0_35 which gave same set of errors. 
I also tried java 1.4 which gave different type of error.  Which version of java should I use? Or is it some other issue ?

Comment: For reference: this question was also [cross-posted to the spark-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/spark-users/ti5UF15YBq4/du_Wzhr3uCEJ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks a lot like an older version of Java is being pulled in by sbt. Spark needs at least 1.6, but somehow sbt is pulling in that older version.

I followed following link to install java 6 on CentOS 5 and remove other JDK and it is working now.

> http://kurinchilamp.kurinchilion.com/2012/11/how-to-install-java-6-on-centos-5-and-remove-other-jdk-jre-version.html